# service refers to an undefined volume invalid compose project make: *** [Makefile:9: compose-start] Error 15

Tags: docker, docker-compose, makefile

I am following this youtube tutorial to create a django website and I am stuck on this step, this is my first time with docker and i researched for a bit on stack overflow to find the cause but the answrs relating were not solving my issue. My code is below for the docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.10"

x-service-volumes: &service-volumes
  -./:/app/:rw,cached

services:
  website:
    image: mama_website:latest
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - *service-volumes
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

This is the code for the MakeFile:

```
compose-start:
   docker-compose up --remove-orphans $(options)
```

and this is the error I am getting:

```
volumes must be a mapping
make: *** [Makefile:9: compose-start] Error 15
```

I have tried indenting the second volumes tag to be inside the services colon, and tried putting -./:/app/ inside the second volumes tag but no luck, it alwasy says that the volumes or services.volumes must be a mapping

Comment: youtube.com/watch?v=ZJ33N3ABIa0&t=884s is the link to the tutorial. The part that caused this question is at 14:44. I will try the current solution which I appreciate very much this weekend and let you guys know if it solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your YAML syntax has one level of list too many.  Probably the right place to fix it is in the service definition

```yaml
volumes: *service-volumes  # not in an inner list
```

What's happening in the YAML syntax it that the `&service-volumes` anchor points to a YAML list node.  Inside your `volumes:` list, you have a list, and the first item of that list is the `*service-volumes` reference; that is, the list contains a list containing the volume mapping.

```yaml
# after resolving the alias reference, inline list syntax
volumes: [ [ './:/app/:rw,cached' ] ]
```

I'd consider removing some or all of this syntax.  It looks like this mount might be intended to overwrite all of the application code in the image; this can result in inconsistent behavior if a target system has different code or if the local filesystem layout doesn't match the Dockerfile.  Consider removing this setup entirely.  If you want to keep it to simulate a local development environment inside an otherwise isolated container, it's probably not something you'll need to reuse between containers, and you could at least get rid of the YAML anchor syntax.

```yaml
volumes:
  - './:/app/:rw,cached'  # not via a YAML anchor
# (also consider removing this block entirely)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works with the last line of code you wrote!